# conflicting CSS with JavaScript menu/navigation

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi i'm using CSS to vertically and horizontally center my content. After adding a JavaScript menu for site navigation, the sub-menus are pushed outside the container as such:
[image]
When i removed the class, the menus appeared as intended:
[image]
The HTML div for calling the CSS are as follow:
`<div class="container-Main">` and the CSS for container-Mask are as follow:

```
.container-Main {
    display: -webkit-flexbox;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Is there anyway to remedy this situation? Thank you in advance.

Comment: How is JS related to the question?

Comment: The menu is done with JS.

Comment: Yes, but how it is related to the question? What kind of JS are you waiting to get as an answer? How can we use JS knowledge to solve the issue?

Comment: I’m just trying to figure out if the improper display is the JS issue or the CSS issue. Possibly a work around...

Comment: It's not possible to say based on the information in the post. Please see how to create a [mre].